# Array_Formula + VLookUp not showing a table

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I'm trying to extract in Google Sheets the duplicated fruits of the table depending on the date (I want to keep the newest). So I use a VLookUp but I only can extract one column. I've tried putting `{}` with column numbers between `{1;2;3;4}` but it doesn't work.

Is there any way to make this with only a formula?

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A1:A6);A1:D6;1);""))`

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A:D; 4; 1); 9^9; 2; 1; 0)
```